# Join two tables to get group by result including columns of both tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two different tables but one tables has primary key of another one. I am doing group by on one table, but need a particular column in result of another table.

Table1 Transaction {
Column transaction_id,
Column currency
}
Table2 Payment {
Column payment_id,
Column transaction_id,
Column user_id,
Column pay
}

I want to get result in such a way that it is grouped by user_id and currency. Result has sum of pay for different user_id, currency combination.

For example

```
Transaction
transaction_id   currency
1                Dollar
2                Yun
3                Dollar

Payment
payment_id  transaction_id user_id pay
1           1              1       30
2           1              2       20
3           2              1       10
4           3              1       30
```

Result should have:

```
User_id 1
Currency Dollar
Pay 30

user_id 1
Currency Yun
Pay 10

user_id 2
Currency Dollar
Pay 20
```

Comment: Do what you said in your question title: join those tables and do a GROUP BY ...

Comment: I tried to get result of combination of user_id and Pay doing group by. I know we need to use inner join to join two tables to get currency from different table, but not able to achieve desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very simple `Join`

```
Select  P.User_Id, T.Currency, Sum(P.Pay)
From    Payment         P
Join    Transaction     T On T.Transaction_Id = P.Transaction_Id
Group By P.User_Id, T.Currency
```

Comment: Now if i want to add where clause in Payments where should i add that?

Comment: Right before the `Group By`

Comment: Thanks, I need to improve my joins for sure. Keep helping, keep rocking... :)